# Deploying Rails on Apache on Mac OSX - 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I have browsed over 100 links in the past hour, and nothing has helped. What I'm trying to do is simple: deploy a rails app on apache using passenger. The issue I'm getting is a 403 Forbidden error. My setup:

I run these two commands:

```
sudo gem install passenger
rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Then in `etc/apache2/other` I create a file called `Passenger.conf` with:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /Users/maq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.14/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /Users/maq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.14
PassengerDefaultRuby /Users/maq/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby
```

Then in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`, I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName rails.local
   DocumentRoot /webapps/coolapp/public
   <Directory /webapps/coolapp/public/>
      AllowOverride all
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then in my `/etc/hosts` file, I add this entry:

```
127.0.0.1 rails.local
```

Then, I change permissions on my `webapps` directory:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /webapps
```

I then restart Apache:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

NONE OF THIS IS FIXING THE ISSUE. I keep getting the same thing when I access rails.local in my browser:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.  Apache/2.2.22
>   (Unix) DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/4.0.14 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8x
>   Server at rails.local Port 80

Someone for the love of god tell me what the issue could be.

Comment: Where does `/webapps` live and who owns it?

Comment: @AndréDion it lives in my root directory `/`, the same place where `etc`, `var` are located. I ran chmod 755 on it. Not sure what you mean by who owns it

Comment: I believe Apache runs as user: `_www` and group: `_www` on **OS X**; though this may be limited to OS X Server?!?

Answer (score 0):

Apache won't have permission to access `/`. You should be serving up your websites from `/Library/WebServer/Documents/` or—depending on what group Apache is configured to run under ([`wheel`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_%28Unix_term%29) by default in OS X)—you can try `sudo chown -R root:wheel /webapps`

**Edit**

My `httpd.conf` configuration has the following user/group:

```
User: [my user] # is an admin user
Group: staff
```

Comment: In my httpd.conf file, it has: `User _www Group _www`. Should I change this to wheel?

Comment: @Meltemi so what should I do? Running `sudo chown -R root:wheel /webapps` has not fixed the issue.

Comment: @maq Anytime you make a configuration change you have to restart Apache.

Comment: @AndréDion I did restart Apache. I tried both of your recommended solutions - neither worked.

Comment: @AndréDion regarding your latest edit, is this just your user account that you're signed in under? How do I find out what group this belongs to for me?

Comment: take **Rails** & **Passenger** out of the equation. Can you serve a static `index.html` file from, say, `/testapp`?

Comment: @Meltemi no apparently not. I kept the same vhost configuration except changed DocumentRoot and Directory to /testapp, and in /testapp I put a index.html file, ran chmod 755 on testapp directory, getting 403 error.

Comment: @maq `[my user]` resolves to the same user I log in as (run `whoami` to figure that out). The original configuration matched yours (`_www`/`_www`) but I changed that so I could serve up sites from `/Users/[my user]/Sites` as `http://localhost/`

Comment: @Meltemi ok wait a minute. testapp actually worked. Now I'm getting a 500 error for the rails app, served from /webapp directory. The apache issue was that I was using `sudo apachectl restart`, when apparently I should have been doing `sudo httpd -k restart`

Comment: Everything seems to be working now. I'm getting Passenger run time issues now, but that's a different issue. The issue was after all that I should have been using `httpd start/stop/restart` instead of `apachectl start/stop/restart`. Not sure what the discretion is there.